# Grouping duplicates in order (not your typical filter duplicates)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, duplicates, filtering

I have a strange situation for filtering duplicates.

I have to turn this

```
[
  {name: A, number: 1, order: 1},
  {name: B, number: 1, order: 2},
  {name: C, number: 1, order: 3},
  {name: D, number: 2, order: 4},
  {name: E, number: 2, order: 5},
  {name: F, number: 1, order: 6}
]
```

Into

```
[
  [
    {name: A, number: 1, order: 1},
    {name: B, number: 1, order: 2},
    {name: C, number: 1, order: 3},
  ],
  [
    {name: D, number: 2, order: 4},
    {name: E, number: 2, order: 5},
  ],
  [
    {name: F, number: 1, order: 6}
  ]
]
```

I have been able to put duplicates into their own arrays but this extra step has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach creates a new subarray each time it notices that the current object's number property is not the same as the last object's number property. Otherwise, it adds the current object to the most recent subarray.

It adds these subarrays to the accumulator of the reduce operation. Note that this approach uses a [comma expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) to avoid needing braces and the "return" keyword.

```js
const data = [{"name":"A","number":1,"order":1},{"name":"B","number":1,"order":2},{"name":"C","number":1,"order":3},{"name":"D","number":2,"order":4},{"name":"E","number":2,"order":5},{"name":"F","number":1,"order":6}];

let result = data.reduce((a,c,i,d)=>
  (d[i-1]?.number!==c.number ? a.push([c]) : a[a.length-1].push(c), a), [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thats great! Of course, the reduce method would be perfect for this because it goes through the array one index at a time. I had to break it down to understand it so thanks for the crash course in using the comma operator.